# Apply a function which takes a DataFrame column as parameter to entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which takes a column of a DataFrame as parameter. I want to apply it to all the columns of a DataFrame without looping.
I've already looked into the function apply, but I don't understand how to use it in my context.

Here is my function:

```
def shortlong_oneasset(asset):

ret = pd.DataFrame()

n_horizons = len(horizon)
for i in range(n_horizons):
    r = compute_yields(asset, horizon[i], "horizon")
         
    r.loc[r[asset.name] < short_threshold, asset.name] = int(-1)
    r.loc[r[asset.name] > long_threshold, asset.name] = int(1)
    r.loc[(r[asset.name] != -1) & (r[asset.name] != 1), asset.name] = 0
    
    
    ret = pd.concat([ret, r], axis = 1)
    
    ret.rename(columns={asset.name: horizon[i]}, inplace = True)

ret = ret.iloc[:,~ret.columns.duplicated()]

#ret = pd.merge_asof(dates.to_frame(), ret, left_on="Dates", right_on="Dates")
return ret
```

The "asset" parameter is a column of a DataFrame, for example:

```
shortlong_oneasset(data['column 1'])
```

Here my DataFrame is named "bonds". I tried to do:

```
test = bonds.apply(lambda x: shortlong_oneassetaverage(x), axis=1)
```

or

```
bonds.apply(shortlong_oneasset)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post sample data as well as expected output

Comment: I think you want `bonds.agg(shortlong_oneassetaverage))`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

Comment: Thanks I eventually chose to use another function and now it works!